# My car won't shift

Tags: transmission, hyundai, tiburon

I drive a hyundai tiburon gt and my stopped shifting into gear while I was at a stop light. Now it doesn't go into gear at all even when the car is off. The clutch pedal still has pressure when I press it but the shifter won't engage into gear. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Will it not go into *any* gear? Does it grind or does it just not want to get into gear (push and pull as you like, but never finds a gear)?

Comment: Had the same problem, mechanic was going to change my transmission when he found that it was only the flywheel that broke, could be as simple as the transmission control module though

Answer (score 1):

Either the shifting mechanism has slipped so it needs adjustment or the gearbox has a problem - if the second it will need to come out for repair.

Has the oil level been checked?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the clutch slave cylinder might have failed.

I don't know Hyundai, but I confirmed it is a master/slave setup. In general the clutch pedal works a master cylinder on the firewall near the brake master cylinder, which uses fluid to activate the slave cylinder which pushes a lever to disengage the clutch plates.  If you can trace the fluid line to find the slave, you can have a helper activate the pedal and see if the slave is moving the lever or not.

If it's failed, luckily it's a $20 part...

(Oops just noticed this an old post... sorry!)